# Steinberg UR22 and UR24C signal is panned

Tags: audio, audio-interfaces, panning, problems, steinberg

I have a problem with my Steinberg UR22, the sound has started to feel stronger by about 5-10% in the left channel (headphones). I thought it was a HW problem so I ordered a new sound interface, this time a Steinberg UR24C. But after reinstalling the drivers I was disappointed, the sound in the headphones (and maybe in the monitors, but I can't judge it exactly there) is now about 5-10% stronger in the right channel. When I try to play mono sound in DAW, the level is the same in both channels (visually), so there is no problem there.

I guess it's a SW problem, maybe Windows 10 update, since I started to notice it only recently on UR22? I have no idea, but if you have any idea how to solve it I will be very happy, because it irritates me terribly and I am not able to work efficiently.

Thank you

Comment: I'd have at least checked this using tones, on something with a meter, before leaping to it being the interface.

Comment: DAW meter with mono signal is correct visually, but in headphones it is panned. I tried like 5 different headphones and it behaves the same.